# Why does strlen cause SIGSEGV when called from JNI code (64bit)?

Tags: c, java-native-interface, 32bit-64bit

I am a bit baffled by a bug I am currently experiencing while trying to implement some logic using C and C++ in combination with JNI and Java.

I distilled it to a simple example, which causes the crash every time when compiled for 64 bit on Linux. When using 32bit, it works ok. :S

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>

char * strlenTest()
{
    int size = 100;
    char * string = (char *) malloc(size * sizeof(char));
    int i;
    for ( i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        string[i] = 'a';
    }
    string[50] = '\0';
    printf("string = '%s'\n", string);
    int length = strlen(string);
    printf("string length = %d\n", length);
    return string;
}
```

And the calling method that crashes:

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_foo(JNIEnv *env,
        jobject thiz, jstring dexPath) {
    printf("calling test()\n");
    char * test = strlenTest();
    printf("calling strlen in jni\n");
    int testLength = strlen(test);
    printf("length:%d\n", testLength);
    }
```

Output:
64 bit:

```
calling test()
string = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
string length = 50
calling strlen in jni
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f63cbefb6fa, pid=9563, tid=140066607630080
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (7.0_79-b14) (build 1.7.0_79-b14)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (24.79-b02 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Derivative: IcedTea 2.5.5
# Distribution: Ubuntu Vivid Vervet (development branch), package 7u79-2.5.5-0ubuntu1
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libc.so.6+0x8b6fa]  strlen+0x2a
```

32bit:

```
calling test()
string = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
string length = 50
calling strlen in jni
length:50
```

Makefile:

```
MARCH=-m64

CXX      = g++
CXXFLAGS =  -ansi -g -O0 $(MARCH) -fPIC  -I../.. -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/include -I/usr/include -Dunix -Wformat=0
CC       = gcc
CCFLAGS  = -g  -O0 -fPIC $(MARCH) -I../.. -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/include -I/usr/include -Dunix -Wformat=0
OBJS     = bugtest.o dexFileParser.o miniunz.o unzip.o ioapi.o 

libname.so : $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $(OBJS) -lz  $(MARCH) -shared

%.o : %.cpp
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $< 

%.o : %.c
    $(CC) -c $(CCFLAGS) $<

clean: 
    rm *.o
```

The weird thing is, `strlen` works in the method itself,but when the `char *` is returned to the JNI C function, it somehow crashes, and only in 64 bit.

I really don't understand what is going on. Can someone point out the error?

Comment: Please could you supply your build options (gcc) - have you got -fPIC added. I seem to remember this might fix library calls - if it's still in the latest version you are using.

Comment: @Neil I added the relevant Makefile.

Comment: @Peterik, I took a gamble and posted an answer, however I note now that you have -fPIC included (after seeing the makefile).   Please at least review the post from the ubuntun forum and let's hope this might help!

Comment: You need to use a debugger. You can set a breakpoint in java in a java debugger before the call to your native code, and then attach gdb to your process and set a breakpoint in your native code, and then see what's going on in the debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that the issue was a missing `.h` file that declared the functions.
The compiler did already show a warning that I ignored:

`initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast`

So when I added a `.h` file that declared the `char * strlenTest();` function properly, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a gamble here and suggest the following...

This was taken from http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1942105 (google is great!)

The problem was found using the following command line -

```
gcc -c -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/include/linux HelloWorld.c -o libHelloWorld.so
```

The issue was when attempting 64bit, 32bit worked fine -

The answer, which reported as working was ..

```
gcc -c -fPIC -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/include/linux HelloWorld.c

gcc -shared -o libHelloWorld.so HelloWorld.o
```

running the example -

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH} java HelloWorld
```

Please review the full post and I hope this will aid you with your problem.

Comment: I did not have included the /linux dir, unfortunately that did not solve it. All the other options I already have implemented. Too bad, but thanks for the try!